# Kotlin Unresolved reference while trying to use array of different types items

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main() {
val arr = arrayOf("hello",3,true)
for(item in arr) if(item is Int)  println(item + 20 )
// print(arr[1] + 20)
}
```

I created an array of String, Int and Boolean.
I can do the summation in the for-loop. However, if I am trying to do the `print(arr[1] + 20)`   there is an "Unresolved reference" problem.
Can someone explain this to me? Thanks.

Comment: Also, in general, it's not a great idea to have item of different type in an array,

Comment: “I created an array of String, Int and Boolean”.  What you actually created is an `Array<Any>` (that just happened to initially contain a String, an Int, and a Boolean).  When you pull out a value, all the compiler knows is that it's an `Any` — unless you check it yourself, as you do within the loop.  But that doesn't tell you anything about it outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've said, the array contains mixed types, so the compiler can't infer that `arr[1]` is an integer. The difference in your loop is that you explicitly check that `item` is an integer, so it can do what is called a [smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#smart-casts).

Therefore you would either have to cast it, or reconsider your structure, which might be a better choice. You probably want a class here that can hold a string, integer and boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You may think that youbare trying to do Int + Int. But the array is of type Any. Therefore you have Any + Int which is not a valid function. You could do (arr[1] as Int) + 20